# How do you use EclipseLink 2.3 as persistence provider in NB 7?

Tags: netbeans, eclipselink

I downloaded the latest EclipseLink 2.3 and want to give it a try. But I cannot find a way to choose EclipseLink 2.3 as a persistence provider in NB7.

Here's what I did. 
1. Go to my project's persistence.xml. In Design view-> Persistence Provider drop down menu -> New Persistence Library 
2. I added the EclipseLink 2.3 jar files and gave it a name. 
3. Hit OK.

Nothing happened. It still shows "EclipseLink (JPA 2.)(Default) as my Persistence Provider. And I cannot find the newly created library in the drop down menu. (But if I go Project Properties->Libaries->Add Library I can see it got created).

So how do i use EclipseLink 2.3 as a persistence provider in NB7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your Libraries list contains your EclipseLink 2.3 jar and that the persistence.xml file contains the following line:
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider

You will be using version 2.3 of EclipseLink. As for the display in netbeans, I'm not sure why it wouldn't update but I wouldn't worry about it.

FYI, I've been using EclipseLink 2.3.0 in Netbeans via the method I've described above and it works fine.

Comment: I also have the following line in my persistence.xml:

Comment: <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">. Should I change them accordingly?

Comment: That line is correct. You want to specify 2.0 for the version as well as the xsd file.