# What is wrong with my NamedQuery

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, netbeans

What is wrong with this `NamedQuery`?

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "Queries.findQueryIdsByRoleOfSameSid",
 query = "SELECT q "+
         "FROM Queries q "+
         "WHERE ((q.issueRole = :issueRole) AND "+
         "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Queries qb WHERE ( (q.sessionId=qb.sessionId) AND (q.issueRole=qb.issueRole))) IS NOT EMPTY)"+
         "ORDER BY q.reqTime "),
```

and this is the Queries Entity attributes:

```
public class Queries implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "query_id")
    private Integer queryId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "issue_time")
    private int issueTime;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "issue_role")
    private int issueRole;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "req_time")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date reqTime;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "sucess_flag")
    private int sucessFlag;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "session_id")
    private String sessionId;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "queriesQueryId")
    private Collection<Statement> statementCollection;
```

I am getting this error,  and the modul is not deployed:

> ```
> Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query 
> [Queries.findQueryIdsByRoleOfSameSid: SELECT q FROM Queries q WHERE 
> ((q.issueRole = :issueRole) AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Queries qb WHERE 
> ( (q.sessionId=qb.sessionId) AND (q.issueRole=qb.issueRole))) IS NOT EMPTY)ORDER 
> BY q.reqTime ], line 1, column 44: syntax error at [=].
> Internal Exception: MismatchedTokenException(82!=84). Please see server.log for 
> more details.`
> ```

FYI, I am working with netbeans 7.2.1, default `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider(JPA 2.0)` in `persistence.xml`

I even tried to upgrade the eclipsLink version to 2.6, but failed. I don't know why, I exactly followed these instrctions 
[How do you use EclipseLink 2.3 as persistence provider in NB 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017359/how-do-you-use-eclipselink-2-3-as-persistence-provider-in-nb-7)
And also this one
[Adding the latest EclipseLink version to a Netbeans project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276576/adding-the-latest-eclipselink-version-to-a-netbeans-project)

Please help me out

Comment: line 1 column 44 of the query is what ? there is the problem ...

Comment: as COUNT(*) expression that evaluates to number,instead of IS NOT EMPTY
,  I changed it to > 1  . But still no success :( Any other suggestion?

Comment: @maria Exception message is still the same?

Comment: @maria BTW I spotted that before `ORDER BY` there's not space... Even though it may be not the cause of problem -  add space  just for sake of clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner query is wrong. `SELECT COUNT(*)` returns a `Long`, so you can't use `IS NOT EMPTY` (it's meant for collections).

Use `> 0` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this formatted version of your query:

```
SELECT q 
FROM Queries q 
WHERE (
        (
            q.issueRole = :issueRole
        ) 
        AND 
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM Queries qb 
            WHERE (
                (
                    q.sessionId=qb.sessionId
                ) 
                AND 
                (
                    q.issueRole=qb.issueRole
                )
            )
        ) IS NOT EMPTY
    )
ORDER BY q.reqTime
```

`IS NOT EMPTY` part refers to `COUNT(*)` expression that evaluates to **number**. From docs:

> The `IS [NOT] EMPTY` expression applies to collection-valued path expressions. It checks whether the particular collection has any associated values.

In your query that part says that `NUMBER IS NOT EMPTY`. **`IS NOT EMPTY` should follows set of rows result - not a number!** Change `IS NOT EMPTY` to simple condition like so:

```
...
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM Queries qb 
    WHERE (
        (
            q.sessionId=qb.sessionId
        ) 
        AND 
        (
            q.issueRole=qb.issueRole
        )
    )
) > 0 -- instead of IS NOT EMPTY
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is there is no space after `IS NOT EMPTY)`.

Please check all the spaces since you are concatenating